# send data from phone to PC via WIFI

Tags: android, sockets, wifi, android-wifi, android-wireless

In my application, I want to send some data(say, "Hello") from my app to my PC over WIFI network. In PC, a service will listen to that data. But i don't have any idea of sending data over WIFI. I didn't get any proper references too. can someone help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Socket, ServerSocket, ... as in any Java app. How will you implement the PC service?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a propper protocol which both, your server and your phone can easily deal with.

If you don't send sensitive data, I think easiest would be HTTP

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you want the service on the PC to do with the received data, really. For all I know, you might find some off-the-shelf software that can help you set up this service. However, as others mention here, http is definetely the easiest way to do this. If you cannot find any existing software for the "listening pc", you'll need to write a program that listens at a predetermined port for http traffic (I wouldn't use the standard http port, 80, since you might run into conflicts with existing http software). You can do this quite easily in java, using Serversocket and/or Socket (as Tobias Rizau mentions above). Personally, I'd write a C/C++ program, since imo. that makes a better service, but that's absolutely not necessary (especially if you only know Java).